# How to enumerate multiple columns in a kdb table?

Tags: kdb

I want to partition a kdb table, so I need to enumerate its symbol columns first. I use the `.Q.en` operator for this task:

```
mytable_mem_enum: .Q.en[`$sym_path] mytable_mem

/generate partition schema
(`$db_path;``!((17;2;9);(17;2;9))) set ([]ts:`time$(); msg_type:`symbol$(); price_type:`byte$(); memo:`symbol$())

/store
(`$db_path) upsert (select ts,msg_type,pricetype,memo from mytable_mem_enum)
```

Q creates a file called `sym` under the directory I specified in `sym_path`. Does this file contain enumerations for all symbol columns? What is the difference between `.Q.en` and this syntax:

```
([] ti:09:30:00 09:31:00; s:`:/db/sym?`ibm`msft; p:101 33f)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.Q.en`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qen-enumerate-varchar-cols) does enumerate any columns of type symbol in the table.

It is essentially no different to doing the enumeration *by hand* except for the convenience of a simple function.

Comment: I wonder, does .Q.en always creates a 'sym' file or it's possible to choose another name? If we do enumeration manually we have to create one file for each symbol column, I think.

Comment: You can examine the `k` source code of .Q.en to find out exactly how it does what it does. It is defined in `q.k` or you can see it by evaluating `.Q.en`. The short answer is, yes it is possible and you do not have to have separate files for each column. You could for example, make a new version of .Q.en to enumerate based on your own sym file.

Comment: The function `.Q.ens` has since been added which takes the format `.Q.ens[dir;table;name]`, where `name` allows for a custom name to be passed.